# Add returns from a loop into a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, loops

Here I am appending a multiline string to an element in jQuery, what I want to do is add a string return from each value in the for loop.

```
$("songs-table-tr").append('tr id="songs-table-tr'+count+'" style="display: none">\
                                    <td>\
                                    </td>'+$("#song-list li input").each(function() {
                                        text = $(this).val()   
                                    })+'\
                                    </td>')
$(".todolist-modal").modal("toggle")
```

If anyone knows how to do this, it would be a great help. Please tell me if the question makes sense or if I need to reword it.

Comment: you can only *return* once from a block of code. do you mean that you would like to use each value somewhere else?

Comment: Now what do you expect you would get? What would `$(this)` be and where is the `text` variable defined? What do you want to do with the `text` variable?

Comment: @Icepickle I know it wouldn't work, I just needed to demonstrate the idea. I want to append each return value from the loop into the middle of the above string. For example, if the for loop return the string "Example1" on the first iteration and "another string" on the second and so forth, I want all those string to be added in the middle of the larger string as such + "example1" + "another string" +...

Comment: @Ted Yes I would like to use each value from the for loop and add it into the string. "string1"+ "string2"+"string3"

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var finalstring = '';

$("#song-list li input").each(function() {
                                        finalstring = finalstring + $(this).val();   
                                    });

$("songs-table-tr").append('tr id="songs-table-tr'+count+'" style="display: none">\
                                    <td>\
                                    </td>'+finalstring+'\
                                    </td>');
$(".todolist-modal").modal("toggle");
```

You have to first loop through the song-list li to generate a string. After that you can append final generated string to song-table-tr in a single shot.

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the result so I can understand. @jamesjake